# Parenthesis Tuple(?) Syntax in C#

Tags: c#

I just saw the following syntax in code: `(int, string) testTwo`

It seems to mimic a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), but the return types are incompatible with a Tuple. Example:

```
Tuple<int, string> test = Test.Get(); // This doesn't work
(int, string) testTwo = Test.Get(); // This works

public static class Test
{
  public static (int, string) Get()
  {
    return (1, "2");
  }
}
```

Seems like you can name the params too, but this appears to be for readability only, e.g.:

`public static (int foo, string bar) Get()`

1. What is this syntax called?
2. What's the real world use case?

Comment: It doesn't "mimic" a Tuple, it is a Tuple.  Specifically a [`ValueTuple<int, string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-7.0).  c# has some built-in syntax sugar to interpret expressions like `(int, string)` as value tuples.

Comment: @dbc Why doesn't testTwo work then? If it's a tuple, it seems like it should consistently perform as a Tuple.

Comment: It's a value tuple, I personally use them all the time when I need to return several different values from a single method and don't want to create a micro-class just for that one use case.

Comment: @VSO because the [`Tuple<T1,T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=net-7.0) class is a different type than the [`ValueTuple<T1, T1>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-7.0) struct.  I.e. .NET Core has two completely types for tuples, one a class and one a struct.  The `(int, string)` syntax sugar happens to map to the struct, not the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a Tuple in parentheses it's a value type, specifically it's a `System.ValueTuple`.  `System.Tuple` is a reference type.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I didn't understand. `System.ValueTuple<int, string> test = Test.Get()` works.

Answer (score 4):

There are two [tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuples-vs-systemtuple) in the modern C#/.NET - "old" ones - series of [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=net-7.0) classes and [value tuples introduced in C# 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-features-in-c-7-0/#tuples) which are syntactic sugar based on series of [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-7.0) structs and there is no conversions between those two (though both can be deconstructed - `var (i1, i2) = Tuple.Create(1,2);` and `var (i1, i2) = (1,2);` both are a valid code).

> ### Tuples vs `System.Tuple`
>
> C# tuples, which are backed by `System.ValueTuple` types, are different from tuples that are represented by `System.Tuple` types. The main differences are as follows:
>
> - `System.ValueTuple` types are value types. `System.Tuple` types are reference types.
> - `System.ValueTuple` types are mutable. `System.Tuple` types are immutable.
> - Data members of `System.ValueTuple` types are fields. Data members of `System.Tuple` types are properties.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [*Tuple type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) which maps to `System.ValueTuple`, a value type, available in .NET Core and Framework 4.7+.

A `ValueTuple` and a `Tuple` are distinct, incompatible types.

The syntax with parentheses is [tuple assignment and deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-assignment-and-deconstruction).